# Which one is better for defining the Repository Interface in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

My team used the Laravel Framework for a new project and we choose the Repository design pattern. I'm implementing the Class Interface and uses it in the Repository class, by implement own Interface.
I have some controversy with my team about the defined repository interface, with 3 cases.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Repositories\Interfaces;
    interface UserInterface { }
```

Inside this interface

```
/**
    * Pattern 1
    *
    * @param array $parameters
    * @return App\Models\User
    */
    public function get(array $parameters = []);
```

and

```
/**
* Pattern 2
*
* @param array $parameters = []
* @return App\Models\User
*/
public function get(array $parameters = []);
```

and

```
/**
* Pattern 3
*
* @param array $parameters
* @return App\Models\User
*/
public function get(array $parameters);
```

In the Repository class

```
<?php
    namespace App\Repositories;
    class UserRepository implements UserInterface 
    {
         public function get(array $parameter = [])
         {
             return App\Models\User::get();
         }
    }
```

The code example is defined as a method get() and descript about this code with PHP DocBlocks, the get method optional require an array parameter and return User models. Talk of the team begins, normally everyone needs a standard for our work, we choose the 2 people to approve on pull request so that branch can merge to Develop branch. The little topic that from the example code above.

What we could be used which one, in this case, it different just at default value in parameter, that empty array.

Thank you all.

Comment: You should return a collection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the one without a default value, and fix the return

```php
/**
* Pattern 3
*
* @param array $parameters
* @return Illuminate\Support\Collection of App\Models\User
*/
public function get(array $parameters);
```

Also, you should have the method return a `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` instead. you dont want a method to return ALL the database entries.

Comment: Thank you for this guide, It's cleary for me. Actually I return many values types the LengthAwarePaginator that one of them.

Comment: @DuckDev84 marking the right return in the phpdoc will help you IDE with method suggestions and correction